# Running ServiceStack with another framework

Tags: asp.net, servicestack

I have a legacy ASP.NET (Web Forms) Website to which I would like to add some API goodness courtesy of ServiceStack 3.9.33.0. The site is hosted as an Application in IIS so that the paths of all URIs start with TheApplication; e.g. http://www.thedomain.com/TheApplication/HeresAPage.aspx.

I would like to add a RESTful api section in the format http://www.thedomain.com/TheApplication/api/widgets/{id}. However, I can't seem to get the
routing right and always end up with 404s.

I have read the article about [running ServiceStack side by side with another framework](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Run-servicestack-side-by-side-with-another-web-framework), but if I'm reading it right it only addresses the case 
where the api portion of the URI is at the root; e.g. http://www.thedomain.com/api/widgets/{id}. For various reasons I need to keep the api section under TheApplication.

What do I need to have in my web.config location path, httpHandler path, AppHost.Configure method, and/or Route attributes to make this happen?

Comment: Can you currently find /metadata on any of those paths?
`thedomain.com/metadata`
`thedomain.com/theapplication/metadata`
`thedomain.com/theapplication/api/metadata`

Comment: Nope, I get 404s for all three of those. Great question - I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Following the article _exactly_, I would expect to find metadata at `thedomain.com/theapplication/api/metadata`

Comment: Double-checking the config settings led me to the fact that it is using an application pool in "Classic" managed pipeline mode. When I switched it to one using Integrated mode, it worked exactly as you predicted. Thank you for your help!